# Uploading pictures in selenium for python (Not loading)

Tags: python-2.7, selenium

I am trying to upload pictures on a website using Selenium for python 2.7.

The pictures does get on the website, but apparently don't load. A picture is worth a 1000 words.

[Not loading image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/korlj.png)

As you can see, the picture is ''loaded'' but does not appear on the website. Also, even though if I wait 10 seconds before sending the whole form, the ad still gets posted without any picture in it. Here's the code I'm using

```
image_input = browser.find_element_by_id('FileUploadInput')
browser.execute_script("arguments[0].type = 'file';", image_input)
image_input.send_keys("picture1.jpg")
```

Also, here is the code of the website I'm trying to upload to.

```
                <li class="jsonly">

            <div id="ImageUpload" class="clearfix form-section placeholders">

                <p class="images-title">Ajoutez au moins une photo. Mettez-en davantage pour montrer différents angles et détails.</p>

                <ol id="UploadedImages">
                    </ol>

                <span class="field-message" data-for="FileUploadInput"></span>

                <div id="ImageDragAndDrop" class="clearfix">
                    <div class="image"></div>
                    <div class="copy">
                        <h3>Glisser-déposer</h3>
                        <p>Glissez et déposez vos photos pour en modifier l'ordre d'affichage.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div id="FileInputWrapper" class="file-input-wrapper">
                    <input type="hidden" name="file" id="FileUploadInput" >

                    <h3>Recevez au moins deux fois plus de réponses en ajoutant des photos</h3>
                    <p>Vous pouvez ajouter jusqu&rsquo;à <span id="MaxImages">10</span> photos, d&rsquo;au moins 300px de haut ou de large (nous recommendons au moins 1000px).</p>

                    <div class="imageUploadButtonWrapper">
                        <button id="ImageUploadButton" type="button" class="button-update-cancel short file-upload-button">
                            Sélectionner les photos</button>
                    </div>
```

As you can see, I'm targeting the FileUploadInput, unhidding it and then sending keys.

Website link : It's in my code sample posted below

And this is the code I'm using so you don't have to code it yourself (username and password included so that it's easier for you, it's a dummy account anyways)
 [My code](http://pastebin.com/r9GN0Cv4)

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to handle wrong `input` field. Try below code:

```
image_input = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@type="file" and @multiple]')
image_input.send_keys("picture1.jpg")
```

Comment: Damn you're good ! Could I ask you how you found that ? I've tried various Xpath with the button and I never saw that one.

Comment: File should be uploaded via `<input type="file">` only. If you can upload file manually, you can be sure that there is already `input` element for that purpose- you shouldn't make changes in `HTML` source.